# How do I print objects to the console in format-list, but also return the objects as objects?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a cmdlet that returns custom objects.

I still want to return the objects, but when running the script I want to also output those objects to the console with format list- like how write-host writes to the console, but its output is not consumed by variable assignments.

So for example I want to be able to use it like this from the console:

```
$ArrayOfObjects = $ArrayOfIPsOrWhatever | MyCoolCmdlet.ps1
```

## This is what the user sees in the console when running that command

```
name: myobj1
prop1: sdfsdfsdf
prop2: sldkjfss

name: myobj2
prop1: swerwew
prop2: kopkpjojpoj
```

BUT they can also use the array of objects (like this $ArrayOfObject[1..2])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell's correspondend of con of command prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818045/powershells-correspondend-of-con-of-command-prompt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be forcing the output on the caller like that; at least use `Write-Verbose`.

But the way to do it is to just write the objects within your cmdlet with `Write-Host` or `Write-Verbose`, *and* return them to the output stream.

To use the formatted output, you can do this mildly convoluted thing:

```
$myObjects | Format-List | Out-String | Write-Verbose
```

You should show your code and explain how it's not doing what you want.

Comment: But I don't want to use the write cmdlets I want to use FL